# Global and local scope in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just a beginner question about local and global scope in python

```
X = 100
#is X a global variable?.We defined it outside the function scope
def foo():
    print(X)
    return X
#it prints 100 and even returns it
def foo():
    X = X + 10
#local error
#UnboundLocalError: local variable 'X' referenced before assignment
def foo():
    global X
    # if X is a global variable why specify again?
    X = X + 10
    return X
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23471004/918959

Answer (score 3):

To modify global copy of a variable you need the to use the `global` keyword, but you don't need `global` if you are only accessing that.

Answer (score 2):

from the [python website](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python):

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.

this means that you can access a global variable inside a function without a `global` keyword. if you want to change it though, you must use the `global` keyword beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

`global` and `nonlocal` are very strange things when I was a beginner.

Just think about it: why do we need them in Python?

It is because we don't need `var`, `let` and such similar things to declare variables.

Think about `Javascript`, it is dynamic script language too and very alike to python, but it needs `var` or `let` or `const` to declare variables.

The most important thing of declaring variables is to determine scope.

**So, in Python, our variables have implicit default scope: current scope where they are defined, and if we want to change scope of some variables, we need use `global` or `nonlocal` explicitly .**

All names on the left side of `=` mean to define variables.

Before executing code of some certain scope, Python will pre-compute all `local variables`, which are those on the left side of `=`. **This is why you got `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'X' referenced before assignment`** in:

```
def foo():
    X = X + 10
```

So, if we look up those names not in defined current scope, just 
follow the rules of scope chain: up, up, up and until `built_in`.

**Remember**: scope of any name on the left side of `=` is default current scope, and you have to assign it(bind something to it) before referring it.

Comment: But if the function was `def foo(): print(x)`, then  the following code `x = 10; foo()` will print `10`.

Comment: @adosar in your case, function foo's scope is same as x, so the x in function foo will look up