# Python error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'score1' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, variable-assignment

I am trying to make a simple dice roll game where two players roll a dice once for five rounds and the person with the highest score wins.

I have already tried setting the score1 variable to 0 within the function and outside of the function however this will cause the score to be reset to 0 every time.

```
#setting the scores as 0 before.
score1=0
score2=0

def round1():
    print('Round 1, lets go')
    input("Player 1 press ENTER to roll dice")
    diceroll1()
    input("Player 2 press ENTER to roll dice")
    diceroll2()
    round2()
#Round 1, calls upon dice roll functions and.

#dice roll function for player 1
def diceroll1():
    import random
    number = random.randint(1,6)
    print("Your number is: " + str(number))
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number + 10
        score1 = score1 + number
        print("Your new score is: " + str(score1))
    else:
        number = number - 5
        score1 = score1 + number
        print("Your new score is: " + str(score1))
    if score1 < 0:
        score1 = 0
    else:
        score1=score1

#dice roll function for player 2
def diceroll2():
    import random
    number = random.randint(1,6)
    print("Your number is: " + str(number))
    score2
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number + 10
        score2 = score2 + number
        print("Your new score is: " + str(score2))
    else:
        number = number - 5
        score2 = score2 + number
        print("Your new score is: " + str(score2))
    if score2 < 0:
        score2 = 0
    else:
        score2=score2
```

I want it to simply add the dice value to the score but I get this error :

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'score1' referenced before assignment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local (?) variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904981/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your indentations are off, which is critical in Python. Also, it is not clear just how those functions are called. You do not give us the full traceback for the error. Please give us a single, complete code snippet that we can run and then see the error for ourselves. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Just a very common question for Python. Below is my answer in somewhere else.

`global` and `nonlocal` are very strange things when I was a beginner.

Just think about it: why do we need them in Python?

It is because we don't need `var`, `let` and such similar things to declare variables.

Think about `Javascript`, it is dynamic script language too and very alike to python, but it needs `var` or `let` or `const` to declare variables.

The most important thing of declaring variables is to determine scope.

**So, in Python, our variables have implicit default scope: current scope where they are defined, and if we want to change scope of some variables, we need use `global` or `nonlocal` explicitly .**

All names on the left side of `=` mean to define variables.

Before executing code of some certain scope, Python will pre-compute all `local variables`, which are those on the left side of `=`. **This is why you got `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'X' referenced before assignment`** in:

```
def foo():
    X = X + 10
```

So, if we look up those names not in defined current scope, just 
follow the rules of scope chain: up, up, up and until `built_in`.

**Remember**: scope of any name on the left side of `=` is default current scope, and you have to assign it(bind something to it) before referring it.

[Global and local scope in python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651307/global-and-local-scope-in-python/56652093#56652093)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `global` identifier.

Some remarks about the code:

1. imports should be on the top of the code. And it is enough to import a library once.
2. You do not have to redefine the value of a variable to its own value. Like this `score2 = score2`. Just don't do it.
3. I suggest you to use a while loop to make the game infinitely or a for loop for a const number of rounds.
4. Go through your code and count duplicates. There are a lot of them. Try to reduce the number.

I modified your code and left some interesting features there, that will help you in the future and now.

```
from random import randint


#setting the scores as 0 before.
score1=0
score2=0


#dice roll function for player 1
def diceroll1():
    global score1
    import random
    number = randint(1,6)
    print(f"Your number is: {str(number)}")

    number += - 5 if number % 2 else 10
    score1 += number

    if score1 < 0:
        score1 = 0

    print(f"Your new score is: {str(score1)}")


#dice roll function for player 2
def diceroll2():
    global score2
    import random
    number = randint(1,6)
    print(f"Your number is: {str(number)}")

    number += - 5 if number % 2 else 10
    score2 += number

    if score2 < 0:
        score2 = 0

    print(f"Your new score is: {str(score2)}")


def game_loop():
    for _ in range(int(input("Raound number: "))):
        print('Round 1, lets go')
        input("Player 1 press ENTER to roll dice")
        diceroll1()
        input("Player 2 press ENTER to roll dice")
        diceroll2()
        print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game_loop()
```

Next, try to make of those two functions one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `global`. Using a `global` identifier is basically like calling it `public`, meaning it can be accessed from all the other parts of the code.
`global score1`

Comment: This should be used for any other variables of similar nature( score2, score3, etc... )